# WPF HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Could anyone explain how HierarchicalDataTemplate works

- What Controls supports HierarchicalDataTemplate?
- What does a control need to support HierarchicalDataTemplate?

**UPDATE**

- What causes the TreeView to render
  the parent and child nodes when the
  same HierarchicalDataTemplate in a
  HeaderedItemsControl only causes the
  parent to be rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such control needs to be of type [HeaderedItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headereditemscontrol.aspx) or derived from it. The current framework controls that do are MenuItem, ToolBar and TreeViewItem.

The HeaderedItemsControl overrides the [PrepareContainerForItemOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.preparecontainerforitemoverride.aspx) method and somewhere along that call path checks for HierarchicalDataTemplate.

Comment: So what causes the TreeView to render the parent and child nodes when the same HierarchicalDataTemplate in a HeaderedItemsControl only causes the parent to be rendered?

Comment: The DataTemplate doesn't "cause" the parent to be rendered. HierarchicalDataTemplate has an ItemsSource property which is automatically applied to the HeaderedItemsControl's ItemsSource in code. Otherwise it's like a usual ItemScontrol.

Answer (score 3):

> What Controls supports HierarchicalDataTemplate?

All controls that inherit `HeaderedItemsControl`, such as `TreeViewItem` or `MenuItem`

> What does a control need to support HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Inheriting from `HeaderedItemsControl` should be enough